# Finding the largest singular value "easily"

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I'm only interested in finding the largest singular value of an $m\times n$ real matrix $A$. I don't need the corresponding (left and right) singular vectors.

1. Is there a way to do so without performing full SVD?
2. Is there an analytical expression? If not, is there an analytical approximation?

Comment: You might be interested in the [Rayleigh quotient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient). This works only for Hermitian matrices, though.

Comment: "principal value" $\: = \:$ "[singular value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Singular_values.2C_singular_vectors.2C_and_their_relation_to_the_SVD)" $\;\;\;$ ? $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: yes. thanks.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586663/why-does-spectral-norm-equal-the-largest-singular-value.

Comment: For simple estimates of singular values you can check "Some simple estimates for singular values of a matrix (Qi, 1984)".

Comment: @catch22:  I'm interested in answering your Question, so in the interest of making it a bit more specific, I edited some details in.  Please review and let me know if I've substantially departed from your intended meaning.

Answer (score 9):

For matrices of general form and not especially small rank, we should not expect a *direct method* to locate eigenvalues or singular values "analytically".  Some discussion of this is [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/1885/651), but the short explanation is that it would be equivalent to a formula for polynomial roots of arbitrary degree.  We instead describe an "easy" iterative approach.

The now-deleted Answer by [KCPP](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/319010/kcpp) said simply, "use power method which is the simplest".  We show that this is the germ of an elementary algorithm to approximate the largest singular value of a (not necessarily square) matrix $A$.  [This numerical topic has been previously discussed at [the Computational Science sister site](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2574/svd-for-finding-the-largest-eigenvalue-of-a-50x50-matrix-am-i-wasting-signifi), along with the more sophisticated [Lanczos algorithm](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1982-38-157/S0025-5718-1982-0637293-9/S0025-5718-1982-0637293-9.pdf).]

The nonzero singular values of $A$ are square roots of the nonzero eigenvalues of $A^*A$. So the [power method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) can be applied to Hermitian matrix $A^*A$ to iteratively approximate its maximum (real) eigenvalue, thus producing as the square root of that the maximum singular value of $A$.

For simplicity of notation, I'll assume $A$ itself is a real matrix of size $m\times n$ with $m\ge n$ as in Vini's Answer.  However the basic idea would apply (forming [Rayleigh quotients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient)) using complex arithmetic and $A^*$ if instead the matrix was not "real and tall".

Generate a "random" initial vector $x_0$, say by picking components from a normal distribution.  The goal here is simply to have a good chance that the initial vector is not "independent" of the maximum value eigenspace of $A^T A$.  One then iterates:

$$ x_{i+1} := \frac{A^T(A x_i)}{||A^T(A x_i)||} $$

Convergence of this iteration is geometric in the ratio of next-largest eigenvalue of $A^T A$ to the largest such eigenvalue.  If the approximation of the right singular vector were of interest, the sequence of $x_i$ would serve this purpose (as $Ax_i$ would approximate the left singular vector).  Setting that aside, the Rayleigh quotients $||A^T(A x_i)||/||x_i||$ are *lower bounds* on the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_{\max}$ of $A^T A$, and their convergence is ordinarily easy to detect (although misconvergence with unlucky initial vectors is possible).

Finally we take a square root of the converged approximation to $\lambda_{\max}$ as our estimate of the largest singular value of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to solve the SVD problem is to reduce the $m \times n$ matrix $A$ (we are assuming that $m \ge n$, otherwise work with the transpose of $A$) to a bidiagonal matrix using orthogonal transformations such that
$$
U^t A V = B, \;\;\; U^tU = I, \;\;\; V^tV = I
$$
where $B$ is an $n \times n$  bidiagonal matrix.  If all the singular values are required then the QR-algorithm or the divide and conquer algorithm is used on the matrix $B$; see the standard textbook "Matrix Computations" by  Gene Golub and Charles Van Loan.   However, if only  a few (or one) singular values is required, bisection is used.