# Spectral radius inequality for normal matrices.

Tags: spectral-theory

I've read in several places now that $\rho(AB) \leq \rho(A)\rho(B)$ holds if the matrices are normal. I've scoured the web for a proof since I can't seem to get there myself. How would one go about to prove this statement? Links to proof is also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for any matrix, the [induced 2-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_norms) of that matrix is defined as $$\|A\|_2:=\sup_{x\neq0}\frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2},$$ and thus by the [spectral theorem for normal matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8339/similar-matrices-have-the-same-eigenvalues-with-the-same-geometric-multiplicity), there exists a basis of eigenvectors of $A$ for $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, and thus $\|A\|_2=\rho(A)$. Similarly $\|B\|_2=\rho(B)$. For $AB$, which is not necessarily normal, we hace $\|AB\|_2=\sigma_{\mathrm{max}}(AB)$, the maximal singular value of $AB$, see also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586663/why-does-the-spectral-norm-equal-the-largest-singular-value).

Now using this, we can see directly that $$\rho(AB)\leq\sigma_{\mathrm{max}}(AB)=\|AB\|_2\leq\|A\|_2\|B\|_2=\rho(A)\rho(B),$$ where the second inequality holds because the induced $2$-norm $\|\cdot\|$ is indeed a norm.

For the first inequality, observe that for any induced matrix $p$-norm, we have  for any $v\in\mathbb{C}^n$, and therefore also for $v$ the eigenvector with norm $1$ corresponding to $|\lambda|=\rho(A)$: $$\|A\|_p:=\sup_{x\neq0}\frac{\|Ax\|_p}{\|x\|_p}=\sup_{\|x\|_p=1}\|Ax\|_p\geq\|Av\|_p=\|\lambda v\|_p=\rho(A)\|v\|_p=\rho(A).$$

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
This seem to be the particular step I'm having trouble with. I simply don't understand when the inequality can be deduced. All I'm getting is that $\rho({AB}) = \rho({BA})$.

Comment: Give me some time to make an edit. My answer is not clear as I wrote it.

Comment: I thought $\rho(AB) = \sigma_{max}(AB)$. Isn't the spectral radius defined as the largest absolute eigenvalue $\vert{\lambda}_{max}\vert$, and the singular value as $\sqrt{\lambda_{max}^2}$?

Comment: Singular values are defined to be the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A^*A$. In case the matrix is not normal (we do not know whether $AB$ is normal), we cannot apply the spectral theorem to conclude that the  singular values are the absolute values of the eigenvalues.

Comment: Ah. Right. Thank you so much Václav. It makes sense now.