# How to compute the norm of a $2\times 2$ matrix (the norm of $A$ is defined as $\sup\{|Ax| : x \text{ is a unit vector}\}$)

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a $2\times 2$ matrix $$
 A=\begin{bmatrix}
  a&b\\
  c&d\end{bmatrix}
$$
Prove that$$\begin{Vmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d\end{Vmatrix}=\sqrt{\frac{|A|^2+\sqrt{|A|^4-4(det(A))^2}}{2}}$$
|A| is defined as$\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}$
I tried to let the input be $(\cos t,\sin t)$ ,but I can’t compute the maximum of $f(t)$

Comment: what is |A| here ?

Comment: |A| is the length of A,it’s the definition of my textbook,It’s the square root of the sum of the square of the all elements in A,in this case |A|=The square root of(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spectral norm of a matrix $A$ is given by $||A|| = \sqrt{\lambda_{\text{max}}(A^*A)}$, i.e. the square root of the largest eigenvalue of $A^*A$. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_p-norms).

The eigenvalues of a $2\times2$ matrix can be expressed in terms of the trace and determinant: $\lambda_\pm = \frac{1}{2}\left(\textrm{tr} \pm \sqrt{\textrm{tr}^2-4\det}\right)$. This can be derived straightforwardly from solving the characteristic polynomial.

Thus, $$||A|| = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(\textrm{tr}(A^*A) + \sqrt{\textrm{tr}^2(A^*A)-4\det(A^*A)}\right)} \\[6pt]
= \sqrt{\frac{|A|^2+\sqrt{|A|^4-4(\det(A))^2}}{2}} $$

Comment: Maybe it's not necessary to use a general result for a $2\times2$ matrix.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question,but the norm in this problem is sup{|Av|},It’s not about the eigenvalue of a matrix ,or can you prove that the two definitions are equivalent?

Comment: @zxZ You can find a proof of why the two definitions are equivalent in this post: [Why does the spectral norm equal the largest singular value?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586663/why-does-the-spectral-norm-equal-the-largest-singular-value). But it's true that using this general result for a $2\times 2$ matrix is a bit overkill.

Comment: @Andreas Now the problem is solved,thank you very much

Comment: Is there any other solutions to compute ||A|| directly (using the definition given in this problem) i.e. ,computing the maximum of (ax+by)^2+(cx+dy)^2 for the input unit vector(x,y)

Comment: @zxZ In principle, it should be possible to compute that maximum directly, e.g. by using Lagrange multipliers to enforce $x^2+y^2=1$. Else, your idea, with letting $(x,y)=(\cos t,\sin t)$ should also work. It will just involve very cumbersome calculations.