# Why is that the matrix $1$-norm and $\infty$-norm are equal to the operator norm, while the $2$-norm is not?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, definition, matrix-norms

I had always assumed that the operator norm of a matrix $A$:

$$\|A\|_p = \sup\limits_{\|v\|_p \neq 0}\dfrac{\|Av\|_p}{\|v\|_p}$$

was the same as the norm of a matrix:

$${\displaystyle \|A\|_{p}= \left(\sum _{i=1}^{m}\sum _{j=1}^{n}|a_{ij}|^{p}\right)^{1/p}}$$

However, this post seems to shatter my assumption: [2-norm vs operator norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/482170). Upon [further examination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm), it seems that the operator norm and matrix norm only coincide (=) for the matrix $1$-norm or the matrix $\infty$-norm (and extremely limited cases for matrix $2$-norm).

Why is this so? Is there a theorem that relates the operator norm with matrix $1$ or $\infty$ norm and show their equality?

---

Note:

[image]

Comment: Your norm of a matrix is what you get when you treat the matrix as a $mn$-vector. But this then ignores the "matrix" structure of $A$ and so why would you expect to get it the same as the operator norm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @user1551 operator norm induced by 1-norm and $\infty$-norm are not equal to matrix 1 and $\infty$ norm. Moreover Forbenius norm or matrix-2 norm is always greater than equal to operator norm induced by 2-norm because operator norm induced by 2-norm is maximum singular value(by definition) and matrix 2-norm is $(\sum_i\sigma_i^2)^\frac{1}{2}$. To see this note :$$\left(\sum _{i=1}^{m}\sum _{j=1}^{n}|a_{ij}|^{2}\right)=trace(A^TA)=\sum_i eigenvalue_i(A^TA)=\sum_i singularvalue_i(A)^2=\sum_i \sigma_i^2$$

Comment: But in Linear and Nonlinear Functional Analysis with Applications
By Philippe G. Ciarlet page 88 it shows that the operator norm induced by 1 norm and $\infty$ norm is indeed equal to matrix 1 and $\infty$ norm...(see picture in question body)

Comment: Okay I see, when I was referring to matrix norm, I was referring to "max absolute colum/row"

Answer (score 1):

No, the vector $1$-norm or $\infty$-norm are not the same as their induced counterparts. E.g.
\begin{align*}
\|(1,0,0,1)\|_1=2&\ne1=\max_{\|v\|_1\ne0}\frac{\|I_2v\|_1}{\|v\|_1},\\
\|(1,1,1,1)\|_\infty=1&\ne2=\max_{\|v\|_\infty\ne0}\frac{\left\|\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1}v\right\|_\infty}{\|v\|_\infty}.
\end{align*}
In fact, the induced $1$-norm of a matrix $A$ is given by the maximum $1$-norm of all columns. Unless $A$ has $n-1$ zero columns, its induced $1$-norm is always strictly smaller than its vector $1$-norm.

Also, the the induced $\infty$-norm of a matrix $A$ is given by the maximum $1$-norm of all rows. In most cases, it is different from the vector $\infty$-norm of $A$.

Comment: I'm sad because Wikipedia says in the induced norm section: "In the special cases of p = 1,2,∞, the norms can be computed or estimated by...(matrix norms)"

Comment: @DonaldJ.Panda I don't understand why you are upset. The mentioned passage is correct (and the induced 1- and $\infty$-norms are more commonly known as the maximum absolute column sum norm and the maximum absolute row sum norm). The OP has perhaps mistaken the column/row sums as double sums.